# How do you deploy a war at startup in apache-karaf

Tags: war, apache-karaf

I have created a war file that I deploy in karaf by running the osgi:install command like

```
osgi:install -s file:/system/com/mywebapp/1.0.0/mywebapp-1.0.0.war
```

How can I configure karaf so that this happens when the karaf instance starts?

I've changed the org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file to start the war feature by default

```
featuresBoot=config,ssh,management,kar,war
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample features.xml for a war file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="feature-set">
    <feature name="my-feature" version="1.0.0"
        xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">

        <feature>war</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:com.foo/mywebapp/1.0.0/war</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

The important part is that the mvn url to the war file "mvn:com.foo/mywebapp/1.0.0/war". If you miss the suffix /war in the path the maven url looks for a jar file.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to create your own features file and start your war from this features file, with it you are also able to set the startlevel and it's dependencies. 
Another way of deploying is to place your war in the deploy folder.